# CSS doesn't appear to be properly working

Tags: css, wordpress

the contact form i have on my front page that im making, has some CSS on it so its all centred, fits inside the white box it creates etc, yet one of the fields doesn't seem to fit inside the white box but everything else does, heres the site.

https://www.traveltradewinds.com/ttw/

When i change the CSS to try and fix it, i noticed that the width being set to 110% fits it in, but then isn't in the centre of the screen as a result, on a side note, the checkbox isn't the default input type checkbox it has a style to it that i haven't added, can anyone help me to show whats going wrong as it looks like ti should work to me?

Many thanks

Edit: forgot to add the CSS code, sorry:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
   .hero .hero-inner {
       width: 100% !important;
       float: left;
       margin-left: 1.38889%;
       margin-right: 1.38889%;

   }
}


.hero .hero-inner {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.38889%;
    margin-right: 1.38889%;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
}

form {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.widget ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


.hero .widget ul li, .hero .widget ol li {
list-style: none;
height: 48px;
margin: 50px 15px;
height: 48px;
 margin: 50px 15px;
}

.hb-submit{
 text-align:center;
 }
```

Comment: You have a max-width applied to .hero and that's probably not enough for the contents to fit in.

Comment: @ConsoleLog i feel very stupid, changing that value fixed it thank you very much EDIT: im still confused about the checkbox though, whats making the checkbox look like that?

Comment: Personally, for this layout, I'll move the phone number and email to the next row as all five inputs won't fit in in one row unless you have a large screen.

Comment: checkbox has this style applied to it. .hotel-booking-search input{    min-width: 200px;} get rid of that and your checkbox will be sorted :)

Comment: Please check my answer below, Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it belongs to hotel-booking.css. Please check this [image: check]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need to use the FORM tag for parent and LIST tag to children. You would use the DIV to create this part and then give 17% of main width to each subDIV.(1% to margin) such as below code:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainDIV {
  background: red;
  width: 80%;
}

.subDIV {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 17%;
  margin: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDIV">
  <div class="subDIV">
  </div>
  <div class="subDIV">
  </div>
  <div class="subDIV">
  </div>
  <div class="subDIV">
  </div>
  <div class="subDIV">
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will be useful.